# How remove special characters in csv-file and keeping umlaut with python

Tags: python, csv, nlp

Hej, I´m new in the python-world and try to clean data of a twitter-corpus for an linguistic-assignment. The tweets are stored in a csv-file and I want to remove the special characters. The german Umlaut is coded in special characters in the csv-file. So I lose all the umlauts when I remove the special characters.
How can I remove the special charakters and at the same time keep the umlaut?
It would be great if somebody could help me.

That is, what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("test_newtest90.csv") 
data = pd.read_csv("train_newtest90.csv") 
import re
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import string
import nltk
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

%matplotlib inline

train  = pd.read_csv("train_newtest90.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test_newtest90.csv")

combi = train.append(test, ignore_index=True)

def remove_pattern(input_txt, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern, input_txt)
    for i in r:
        input_txt = re.sub(i, '', input_txt)
        
    return input_txt    

#Removing Twitter Handles (@user)
combi['tidy_tweet'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(combi['tweet'], "@[\w]*")

#Removing Short Words: bis len 3
combi['tidy_tweet'] = combi['tidy_tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split() if len(w)>3]))

#Removing Punctuations, Numbers, and Special Characters
combi['tidy_tweet'] = combi['tidy_tweet'].str.replace("[^a-zA-Z#]", " ")
```

Comment: Please type your code into your question instead of sending a screenshot. It makes it much easier to work with!

Comment: You've provided no sample input/desired output, but wouldn't `.replace("[^a-züA-Z#]", " ")` work?  Add any other characters you don't want to remove to the replacement list.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Thanks! It works! Can you also tell me how to remove the https and the hashtags (just the pound sign and not the word) from the tweet-corpus?

Comment: @MarkTolonen: And what do you mean when you say I provided no sample input/desired. I´m an absolut beginner, therefore I ask.

Comment: I mean, what does the text you are working on look like, and what do you want it to look like after processing?

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I have a csv-file with around 1500 tweets, the output should be (I think) a text as a list of words, all lowercase, without numbers, special characters, https, german stopwords, hashtags (keeping the keywords). The output should allow me to search the text for frequency distribution, concordance, make wordclouds and plots. If I´m honest I actually don´t know if it´s doable for me. I´m a linguist trying all that from scratch only knowing for sure that I´m having great fun working on that.